# SQL: How To Find The Top String Column Value in a Grouped Query

Tags: sql

When grouping is there a simple way to get the first or top value out of a column.  In the following example I want the last value in [Text] if sorted by [Date] descending.

```
SELECT 
   [Id],
   MAX([Date]),
   TOP 1 [Text],  <-- How do I do do this
   COUNT(*)
FROM
   [ExampleTable]
GROUP BY [Id]
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the text corresponding to that [Id] & that [MaxDate], you can do this:

```
SELECT T2.*, T1.Text
FROM [ExampleTable] T1
     JOIN (SELECT 
               [Id],
               MAX([Date]) MaxDate,
               COUNT(*) Cnt
             FROM
               [ExampleTable]
         GROUP BY [Id]) T2
     ON T1.Id = T2.Id AND T1.Date = T2.MaxDate
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

if [Id] & [Date] form a primary key you will have a single row per (Id, Date) other wise many. If you really want one, either you put other constraints or use MAX or MIN::

```
SELECT T2.*, MAX(T1.Text) Text -- or MIN(T1.Text)
FROM [ExampleTable] T1
     JOIN (SELECT 
               [Id],
               MAX([Date]) MaxDate,
               COUNT(*) Cnt
             FROM
               [ExampleTable]
         GROUP BY [Id]) T2
     ON T1.Id = T2.Id AND T1.Date = T2.MaxDate
GROUP BY T2.*
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

If you want just a value for Text you can use MAX or MIN:

```
SELECT 
   [Id],
   MAX([Date]),
   MAX([Text]),
   COUNT(*)
FROM
   [ExampleTable]
GROUP BY [Id]
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Comment: najmeddine, Not everyone may realize that your last query (with MAX twice) produces results that don't individually appear in the source table. The MAX(Text) value could be the Id's "Text" from a different date than the latest date.

All you get by using two MAX aggregates is one row per Id value. You don't get one row of the original table, though, and it's rare that the two-MAX query is what someone really wants.

Comment: @Steve, it seems that you read only the last part of my answer.  
I detailed 3 cases:  
1- He wants the text corresponding to that Id & that MaxDate  
2- He wants (1) but got more than 1 line per (Id, MaxDate): if that's not ok and he wants always one, he can use Min or Max  
3- He wants just a random text (I said 'a value for Text'), he can use Min or Max.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly, there can be multiple dates for any given id, and multiple text for a given date.

If you use Sql Server 2005

I got this to work

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        DDATE DATETIME,
        VAL VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Table (ID,DDATE,VAL) SELECT 1, '01 Jan 2009', '1'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,DDATE,VAL) SELECT 1, '01 Feb 2009', '2'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,DDATE,VAL) SELECT 1, '01 Feb 2009', '3'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,DDATE,VAL) SELECT 2, '01 Jan 2009', '4'


SELECT  ID,
        DDATE,
        VAL,
        ROWNUMBER
FROM    (
            SELECT  t.ID,
                    t.DDATE,
                    t.VAL,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY DDATE) ROWNUMBER
            FROM    @Table t INNER JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT  ID,
                                MAX(DDATE) AS MAXDATE
                        FROM    @Table
                        GROUP BY ID
                    ) md    ON  t.ID = md.ID
                            AND t.DDATE = md.MAXDATE
        ) RowNumber
WHERE   RowNumber.ROWNUMBER = 1
```