# sql left join +one to many relationship

Tags: sql, left-join

I have three tables - node, content_type_product and share_content.  There *may* be a 1:N relationship beetween node and share_content.  I want to pull out only one record per id.
If there is multiple records in share_content, I want the latest one, that is the highest value of sc.auto_id

```
SELECT sc.uid, n.uid, n.nid, sc.message 
  FROM node n 
    LEFT JOIN content_type_product p ON n.nid = p.nid 
    LEFT JOIN share_content sc ON n.nid = sc.nid 
  WHERE n.nid = 40513 
  GROUP BY sc.nid
  ORDER BY sc.auto_id
```

Comment: You can use ORDER BY sc.auto_id DESC

Comment: The [example](http://sscce.org/) is incomplete without schema (as `CREATE TABLE` statements), sample data (as `INSERT` statements) and desired results for the sample data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select Rows with Maximum Column Value group by Another Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425240/), [How To Find The Top String Column Value in a Grouped Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443979/), [SQL Group by & Max](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299556/)

Comment: ... [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/), [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/), and many, many others.

Comment: "may be a 1:N relationship" -- a.k.a. 1:0..M correspondence ("one to zero or more").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you joining to content_type_product ?? 
But that aside, try

```
 SELECT c.uid, n.uid, n.nid, c.message  
 FROM node n  
   LEFT JOIN share_content c 
      ON c.nid = n.nid  
          And c.auto_id
             = (Select Max(auto_id)
                From share_content 
                Where nid = p.nid ) 
 Where n.nid = 40513  
 ORDER BY c.auto_id
```

Comment: Edited it because your subquery would not return the needed columns to make the join, it would only return the MAX(auto_id) value.

Comment: hmm, how can c.auto_id=uid, message??

Comment: reedited to return it to what was submitted - because that's the only column the subquery NEEDs to return, added code for message field

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT sc.uid, n.uid, n.nid, sc.message FROM node n left join content_type_product p on n.nid = p.nid LEFT JOIN share_content sc on n.nid = sc.nid 
WHERE n.nid = 40513 
GROUP BY sc.nid, sc.auto_id
ORDER BY sc.auto_id DESC
```

Comment: Thank you - works, however - we are looking to group only by sc.nid - as we want only one result.